# tips to track down intermittently freezing iOS UI

Tags: ios, ipad, core-data, deadlock

I wrote a huge iPad app 2 years ago and now I'm getting back to it and upgrading it to iOS5. Its a bit messy as it was my first large iPad app.

Its has a "sync" step that may last for several minutes and these are a bunch of asynchronous method calls that go and fetch JSON from a url and put them into core data. Fairly often, the app will freeze (UI is unresponsive).

What are some good techniques to track down this freezing? The debugger isn't that helpful as unless the code is running on the main thread, you have no useable stack trace. The app often does not recover either which suggests some sort of dead lock situation.

Here is one particular example that might help:

[image]

I paused the execution once I verified that it was frozen. It seems to freeze on the same line every time - a simple assignment. What is going on here? Its so frustrating.

Is this core data access that is causing this? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 29-JUNE-2012**

[Click here](http://pastebin.com/Zq0t27kD) to see the source of the class that does all the Create/Update/Deleting of Core data objects. I just need to stop the freezing/crashing in this app. I know its a mess,  it makes me cringe too. I wrote this 2 years ago with hardly any knowledge of objective-c. I should re-write it but I have to get this working and out of my head in 2 days. Could anyone give me pointers on approaches to get this thread-safe quickly? Could I wrap each method that updates NSManagedObjectContext in grand central dispatch block code?

Comment: When the UI becomes unresponsive it's because you are executing code on the main thread that should be executed in the background.  You can try pausing the app during this freezing and hopefully get a useful stack trace on the main thread...but you probably won't.  The only way I've found really helpful in this scenario is being really critical of the code you're executing and where.  Check all you're web requests and sync related code, and anywhere else you think might be process intensive.

Comment: Another idea (rather than pausing in the debugger and hoping for the best) might be to run the app under Instruments, which will tell you which methods are using the most time. I've found it very helpful for debugging precisely these issues.

Comment: I updated question with link to source - if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed possible that Core Data (in combination with multithreading) is the cause of your troubles - I experienced similar problems.

Here's an excellent article on this topic: [Core Data and threads, without the headache](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/05/04/core-data-and-threads-without-the-headache/)

I also see a call to `performSelector:` in your stack trace. You might want to consider to use Grand Central Dispatch, although that might be a lot to rewrite in your case.

As for your your actual question (tracking down deadlocks), I'd suggest using Instruments as well. Also, look at the status of the other threads.

Comment: So you had freezing issues too?

Comment: Yes, I had freezing issues as well as general strange behaviour (and a few crashes). All of this could be resolved by reducing Core Data usage to the main thread, but I've tried the approach in the mentioned article in a test project, and it works (with multiple threads).

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> The debugger isn't that helpful as unless the code is running on the
>   main thread, you have no useable stack trace.

This isn't true. You get stack traces for all threads.

The fact that it freezes on the same line every time very much suggests that there is something wrong with that line. This is what you are doing:

```
self.friendObj.affiliations = friendObject1.affiliations;
```

So, I would put a breakpoint on that line and when Xcode stops on the breakpoint, analyze the memory of `friendObj1`. Maybe there is something funky going on.

Is there a custom "setAffiliations:" method in your friendObj's class? Maybe somehow an infinite loop is occurring on that line.

I would analyze all of the calls around setting the "affiliations" property of your friendObj and try to determine where your bug is.

Another thought: is friendObj a Core Data object? If so, it should be initialized in a ManagedObjectContext.

Comment: No there isn't a custom setAffiliations method. Its just a string @property. friendObject1 is a coredata object that is in fault when I debug. I wasn't too alarmed though because I heard that core data objects can be in a 'fault' state if they aren't fully resolved yet.

Comment: If friendObj is an NSManagedObject (core data object) it should be initialized using [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"ClassName" inManagedObjectContext:myManagedObjectContext]

Comment: friendObj is NOT a NSManagedObject - friendObj1 IS though.

Comment: How is friendObj NOT an NSManagedObject if friendObj1 is and they are both instances of the same class? You should NOT use NSManagedObject subclasses like normal NSObjects (i.e. [[myClass alloc] init]) -- they are only intended to be created and managed by an NSManagedObjectContext. That might be your issue.

Comment: Sorry, I know its confusing, but a few years ago when I wrote this code and I was getting problems with it, I made exact copies of all my NSManagedObjects and just put an underscore (_) at the end of the copies. That way I could use the copies to populate my view and not worry about faulting core data objects. So the init method you are looking at there is taking all the properties off the NSManagedObject and putting them on the 'copy' (is just an NSObject).